# EXECUTE permission not sufficient to use Stored Procedure. Also have to give SELECT permissions on underlying objects. Why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, user-defined-functions

I have a Stored Procedure in Database A, that references 3 tables in Database B.  Both Databases are on Server 1.

I gave the user:

- public permission on Server 1
- EXECUTE permissions on the Stored Procedure in Database A
- An entry with no permissions on Database B

However, this isn't sufficient. I end up having to assign SELECT permissions to the user, for the 3 tables in Database B (plus SELECT permissions on the schema). Then things work - but **why is that necessary?**

Per Microsoft, this shouldn't be the case:

"Stored procedures take advantage of ownership chaining to provide access to data so that users do not need to have explicit permission to access database objects."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/managing-permissions-with-stored-procedures-in-sql-server

Googling, I see this concept confirmed.

This is my first time assigning permissions to anyone though, so obviously I'm missing something and/or misunderstanding.

Edit: "Permissions only chain within a single database." That explains it!

Comment: Does the tables and the sprocs [have the same owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/managing-permissions-with-stored-procedures-in-sql-server#stored-procedure-execution)?

Comment: Look at Cross-database Chaining

Comment: *"so that users do not need to have explicit permission to access database objects."* not objects in **other** databases. Permissions only chain with in a single database. Depdending on the use case, you either need to look at Cross Database Chaining (this comes with *documented* security warnings) or look at signing your SPs and giving the certificate permissions in the other database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Permissions only chain within a single database." per comment from Larnu.  That explains it.